# How to properly use multiple ||, &, &&

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, syntax, command-prompt

I have this line of code and I am confused on how it would work. How I believe it will run, and that is not what I want, is that the `&& goto continue` will only run in case the email failed since its the closest block of code.

What I want from this line is for it to test the integrity of a .zip, in case it is successful it execute `goto continue` and if it is not, it send an email(`blat`) and then quits.

```
"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" t %ZIPFILE% | FIND "Everything is Ok" || blat -to email@domain.com -server mail.protection.outlook.com -f anotheremail@domain.com -subject "Backup integrity check failed" -body "failed" && goto continue
```

Maybe what I would need is an if > else block of code, however, I want to make sure there is no way to do that just with conditional execution.

Thank you!

Comment: Where is your `continue` label? I'd think it better/clearer to write it as `(check zip file) || (blat & goto :EOF)` with your next step coming on the next line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From Windows XP documentation:](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true)

**&**

> Usage: `command1` & `command2`
>
> Summary: Use to separate multiple commands on one command line.

**&&**

> Usage: `command1` && `command2`
>
> Summary: Use to run `command2` only if `command1` is successful.

**||**

> Usage: `command1` || `command2`
>
> Summary: Use to run `command2` only if `command1` fails.

To achieve what you want, simply swap the conditional code:

```
"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" t %ZIPFILE% | FIND "Everything is Ok" && goto continue || blat -to email@domain.com -server mail.protection.outlook.com -f anotheremail@domain.com -subject "Backup integrity check failed" -body "failed"
```

This way, if successful it will go to continue otherwise send an email.

Comment: how I didn't think about that before! thanks a bunch, have an aewsome day! I just have one question, the `||` after `goto continue` will execute based on the failure of the `find`?